# ¿Es lo mismo utilizar super().metodo() que self.metodo() si en ambos casos se acaba llamando el método de la clase padre?

Tags: python, poo

Tengo una superclase del tipo:

```
class YoSoyTuPadre:
    def parseo_cosas(self):
        # bla
```

y alguna subclase:

```
class Hijo(YoSoyTuPadre):
    def hago_cosas(self):
        # debo llamar a parseo_cosas() de YoSoyTuPadre
```

El tema es que cuando debo llamar a `parseo_cosas()` de la clase padre desde el hijo, suelo utilizar:

```
super().parseo_cosas()
```

Si bien por definición también podría decir:

```
self.parseo_cosas()
```

Sé que con `self.parseo_cosas()` llamo al método de la clase Hijo, el cual al no estar definido es el del padre. Por contra, si llamo con `super().parseo_cosas()` siempre estaré llamado a la clase padre.

¿Existe alguna diferencia en las dos llamadas o su elección es puramente personal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es exactamente lo mismo llamar de forma explicita a la implementación del padre que a la propia, el comportamiento es igual si la hija NO implementa el mismo método pero si lo hiciera lo habitual sería llamar a la propia implementación, aunque existen casos donde es necesario llamar de forma explciita la padre, se ve mejor con algún ejemplo:

```
class Hijo(YoSoyTuPadre):
    def hago_cosas(self):
        # cosas ...
        self.parseo_cosas()
```

Si esa fuera toda la clase hijo el efecto de una llamada u otra es exactamente el mismo, pero aun así sigue siendo preferible llamar al `self`, imagina una clase mucho más grande donde el método se llame en multiples sitios Y llega un momento donde la implementación del padre ya no es suficiente y hay que ampliarla o cambiarla, entonces:

```
class Hijo(YoSoyTuPadre):
    def hago_cosas(self):
        # cosas ...
        self.parseo_cosas()
    def parseo_cosas(self):
        # Parseo desde el hijo por motivos de optimización o similar.
```

En este escenario ya no sería igual llamar desde el `hago_cosas()` al `parseo_cosas()` con `self`o `super()`, si hemos usado el self, la nueva implementación sería utilizada automáticamente por el resto de los métodos de la clase que llamen al `parseo_cosas()`

¿ Cuándo llamar al `super()` ? A menudo es habitual que la re-implementación de un método requiera hacer lo que ya se hace en el padre y luego añadir alguna cosa o hacer algo previo a lo que se hace en el padre, por lo que nos podemos encontrar con casos como este:

```
class Hijo(YoSoyTuPadre):
    def hago_cosas(self):
        # cosas ...
        self.parseo_cosas()
    def parseo_cosas(self):
        # Preparo algunos datos y llamo al padre
        return super().parseo_cosas()
```

En resumen, yo usaría por defecto siempre el `self` y el `super()` sólo cuando es necesario, pensando en que en un futuro la clase puede evolucionar y sobrecargar el método lo que presumiblemente implicará que desde esa clase hijo necesitas la nueva implementación.

**AMPLIACIÓN:**
Existe una casusita que refuerza el uso del `self` y es el caso cuando nuestra clase hija es extendida o heredada, es decir, se utiliza como padre (o madre) para otra clase "nieta" de la primera, en estos casos, si la nueva clase sobrecarga el método lo esperado sería que la nueva implementación sea la que se utilizase.

Esta situación a menudo no es algo necesariamente esperado, pero el software puede tener muchas vidas y no podemos anticipar lo que otros o incluso nosotros mismos en un futuro más lejano podemos hacer para re-factorizar o ampliar el código existente por lo que lo ideal es tender a tomar la decisión que hace el código más robusto, en la medida de lo posible.

Comment: En mi caso no aventuro una implementación del método en la clase Hijo, por lo que super() y self() teóricamente siempre van a tener el mismo funcionamiento. Me gusta lo de dejar super() para cuando extiendes un método

Comment: En muchos casos no será necesario, pero la idea es que "a veces" puede surgir y por eso mismo, dejar el uso de `self` por defecto tiende a ser una opción más robusta generalmente, de hecho la casuistica se complica si la clase hija puede ser a la vez la clase padre de otra, en esos casos el tema se complica, pero por el mismo motivo, lo más probable es que confiar en `self` sea lo deseable.